# Force the page to be loaded only within an IFrame don't work in chrome and safari

Tags: iframe, load

i'm using following script to force a page to be loaded only within an iframe

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    if (frameElement == null) {
        //change location or close
        window.location = "http://site.com/";
        // or window.close();
    }
</script>
```

it work very well in ie and firefox but not in chrome and safari 
any solution for this browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `if (top == window)` instead.